# Android Studio marks Dart spread operator as an error in flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm making a flutter app using Android Studio and I'm using dart's spread operator (`...`) to add a list of generated widgets to a list of widgets. The code is like this:

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        QuestionWidget(questions[_questionIndex].question),
        ..._getAnswerButtons(questions[_questionIndex]),
      ],
    )
```

The code is fine, the app runs without a problem, but Android Studio is marking the spread operator as an error:

[image]

Not only it's annoying, but this causes Android Studio to not recognize the use of the function `_getAnswerButtons` in this line.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Is this a problem with Android Studio? Or is it with the analyzer? Does anyone know how to fix this IDE mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pubspec.yaml, what is your minimum environment SDK version ? If it's inferior to 2.3.0, try and increase it.

Comment: I set my sdk to `sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"` and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the IDE and setting `sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"` solved for me.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52451#issuecomment-598016638